# Is there any point in setting the secure cookie flag for HSTS websites?

Tags: tls, http, cookies, session-management

If my website has HSTS and forced HTTPS (i.e. user won't be able to access the plain HTTP version of the website), is there any point in setting `secure: true` for the cookies?

Comment: _Aside:_ Not all cookies _need_ to be secure.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you should still mark your cookies as secure, for three reasons:

- You dont want them to be exposed just because of a server configuration mishap. What if you move your application to a server with a different configuration?
- HSTS is trust on first use. If your HSTS has expired but your cookies has not, the browser may send them unencrypted. Whether or not there is something responding to plain HTTP is irrelevant here.
- As [Tgr](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/181810/98538) writes, not all browsers support HSTS.

I admit that the benefits aren't huge here, but the cost is basically zero. So set the secure flag!

Comment: The cost is that I'm not able to test my production server API with Postman because it's not a https client...

Comment: @Avery235 Not sure I understand the issue. Postman can hit TLS-protected endpoints just fine. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @user18519 I'm using https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookiesecure. It seems like it's configured to not send back the cookie when the request protocol is not https.

Comment: @Avery235 Yeah, thats what the secure flag does - it instructs the client only to send the cookie over HTTPS connections.

Comment: So I'll have to run all my servers locally instead of just using the production server when doing any development on the front-end...I think the minor security benefit is not worth the hassle for me right now. Thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: Also I assume adding secure header will increase the cookie size, and hence all requests by a few bytes; insignificant but not exactly "zero cost" :p

Comment: @Avery235 there are just so many things wrong with your above replies

Comment: @McMatty would you please point out some of these many things? Thank you :)

Comment: @Avery235 I take it the size thing was a joke, but do note that the secure flag is not present in any request, just the response where you set the cookie. Not that it matters anyway, because it is, well, "basically zero".

Comment: @Avery235 Its very unclear why you would have to run your servers locally. As has been pointed out, Postman does handle TLS. And if you are telling the truth when you say that you have "forced HTTPS", it should not be possible to communicate over plain HTTP, secure cookie or not, right?

Comment: "using the production server when doing any development on the front-end..." - sorry, but I hope that was a joke, too.

Comment: @Avery235 If I understood correctly, your problem is that you're doing plain HTTP requests to a server running locally and therefore cookies are not sent because of the Secure flag. You have these options: 1) Use HTTPS locally, 2) Don't set the Secure flag locally. I'd go with 2 for simplicity, but that means properly testing that Secure is set without that flag and never setting it on production. Actually, I just checked your link, and it tells you exactly this solution a few lines below your quote.

Comment: 1. Using production to test 2. Increasing size 3. Not adding a simple layer of security after a risk to the existing control is highlighted, its turning on a flag after all

Comment: It sounds like the OP here perhaps didn't realize that they could use HTTPS locally? The approach should be largely the same. Using a self-signed certificate is likely easiest. Browsers might need a little configuration to accept that, but it'll work (eg, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate).

Answer (score 14):

[Not all browsers honor HSTS.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=stricttransportsecurity) IE mobile doesn't, for example; desktop IE only does since version 11; cloud-based browsers like Opera Mini don't. Marking your cookies as secure is trivial and good defense in depth.